# Try integration test spring-data-jpa throw MockMVC, but update does not work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, mockmvc

I build a demo application, with spring-data-jpa and spring-boot-web.
I try to build an integration test with MockMVC, which, will call an add interface, then a modify interface, and finally a query interface, and determine if the changes are in effect.
I also use "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql" property, to print sql log in console.
However, in the console, I only see one insert sql, one query sql, and no update sql.
Also, the @PreUpdate annotation I used did not take effect, because the coverage check showed that it was not executed.

But when I test through postman,everything was very normal and as expected: I saw the update sql and it also executed @PreUpdate.

What I did wrong when writing the test cases?

Here is my test code. The Rest Api just call the JpaRepository.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
class TechyoControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    public void should_update_success() {
        String createRequest = "{\"name\":\"name_test\",\"money\":12.3}";
        MvcResult mvcCreateResult = mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/accountItems")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(createRequest))
                .andReturn();
        AccountItemResponse createResult =
                objectMapper.readValue(mvcCreateResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), AccountItemResponse.class);

        // update
        String updateRequest = "{" +
                "  \"name\": \"updated_name\"," +
                "  \"date\": " + createResult.getTransactionTime().getTime() + "," +
                "  \"lines\": [{" +
                "    \"name\": \"line1\"," +
                "    \"money\": 12" +
                "  }, {\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"line1\"," +
                "    \"money\": 12" +
                "  }, {\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"line1\"," +
                "    \"money\": -12" +
                "  }]" +
                "}";
        MvcResult mvcUpdateResult = mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/accountItems/" + createResult.getId())
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(updateRequest))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
        AccountItemResponse updateResult
                = objectMapper.readValue(mvcUpdateResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), AccountItemResponse.class);
        assertThat(updateResult.getId()).isEqualTo(createResult.getId());
        assertThat(updateResult.getTransactionTime()).hasSameTimeAs(createResult.getTransactionTime());
        assertThat(updateResult.getTotal()).isEqualTo(new BigDecimal("12.00"));
        assertThat(updateResult.getAccountItemLines()).hasSize(3);

        // query
        MvcResult mvcGetResult = mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/accountItems/" + createResult.getId()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
        AccountItemResponse getResult
                = objectMapper.readValue(mvcGetResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), AccountItemResponse.class);
        assertThat(getResult.getId()).isEqualTo(createResult.getId());
        assertThat(getResult.getTransactionTime()).hasSameTimeAs(createResult.getTransactionTime());
        assertThat(getResult.getTotal()).isEqualTo(new BigDecimal("12.00"));
        assertThat(getResult.getAccountItemLines()).hasSize(3);
    }
}
```

Here is my entity code

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class BasePO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createTime;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updateTime;

    @PrePersist
    protected void prePersist() {
        Date now = new Date();
        if (createTime == null) {
            createTime = now;
        }
        if (updateTime == null) {
            updateTime = now;
        }
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void preUpdate() {
        updateTime = new Date();
    }

    @PreRemove
    protected void preRemove() {
        updateTime = new Date();
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_item")
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AccountItemPO extends BasePO {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "decimal(10,2)")
    private BigDecimal totalMoney;
    private Date transactionTime;
}
```

This integration test itself does not throw any exception (because the data I return does not contain fields such as updateTime).
Adding breakpoints to the program execution shows that the data is indeed updated, but the create_time/update_time is set to null (even though I used nullable = false)

Here is the sql printed from the console

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        account_item
        (create_time, update_time, name, total_money, transaction_time) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: 
    select
        count(*) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        account_item accountite0_ 
    where
        accountite0_.id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this solution. It worked for me with Spring Boot 2.7.5(include GraphQL)

https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-spring/issues/30#issuecomment-860026650

```
Handler:
         Type = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.servlet.GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration$$Lambda$1547/1627578183 Async:
Async started = true
 Async result = org.springframework.web.servlet.function.DefaultEntityResponseBuilder$DefaultEntityResponse@3ec151c5
```

Somehow I see logs saying async = true. so I think the key is waiting for async to be done